# Make Vue template wait for global object returned by AJAX call

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to wait for certain strings in a sort of dictionary containing all the text for buttons, sections, labels etc.

I start out by sending a list of default strings to a controller that registers all the strings with my CMS in case those specific values do not already exist. After that I return a new object containing my "dictionaries", but with the correct values for the current language.

I run the call with an event listener that triggers a `dispatch()` on `window.onload`, and then add the data to a Vuex module state. I then add it to a computed prop.

```
computed: {
    cartDictionary() {
        return this.$store.state.dictionaries.myDictionaries['cart']
    }
}
```

So now here's the problem: In my template i try to get the values from the `cartDictionary`prop, which is an array.

`<h2 class="checkout-section__header" v-html="cartDictionary['Cart.Heading']"></h2>`

But when the component renders, the prop doesn't yet have a value since it's waiting for the AJAX call to finish. And so of course I get a `cannot read property of undefined` error.

Any ideas on how to work around this? I would like to have the dictionaries accessible through a global object instead of passing everything down through props since it's built using atomic design and it would be insanely tedious.

EDIT:
Adding more code for clarification.

My module:

```
const dictionaryModule = {
namespaced: true,
state: {
    dictionaries: []
},
mutations: {
    setDictionaries (state, payload) {
        state.dictionaries = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    getDictionaries ({commit}) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Dictionaries.init().then(response => {
                commit('setDictionaries', response)
                resolve(response)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

My Store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        cart: cartModule,
        search: searchModule,
        checkout: checkoutModule,
        filter: filterModule,
        product: productModule,
        dictionaries: dictionaryModule
    }
})

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    store.dispatch('dictionaries/getDictionaries')
})
```

Comment: could you show your data object in parent and child component?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim What I've shown you is all in the same component, which is also the parent component. It's a hybrid Vue/MVC solution, so the "checkout" component is being inserted into an element in a Razor view.

Comment: so provide me the structure of the final object done by ajax call

Answer (score 1):

I also would have liked to see some more of your code, but as i can't comment your questions (you need rep > 50), here it goes...

I have two general suggestions:

- Did you setup your action correctly? Mutations are always synchronous while actions allow for asynchronous operations. So, if you http client returns a promise (axios does, for example), you should await the result in your action before calling the respective mutation. See this chapter in the official vuex-docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html
- You shouldn't be using something like window.onload but use the hooks provided by Vue.js instead. Check this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram
- EDIT: As a third suggestion: Check, whether action and mutation are called properly. If they are handled in their own module, you have to register the module to the state.

Comment: The way my module is setup is not the issue, I think.

`const dictionaryModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        dictionaries: []
    },
    mutations: {
        setDictionaries (state, payload) {
            state.dictionaries = payload
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getDictionaries ({commit}) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Dictionaries.init().then(response => {
                    commit('setDictionaries', response)
                    resolve(response)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @Atombob you should update your question with that snippet to be more readable

Comment: The action is being called and data is being returned, this is not the issue. It's just that at the time of rendering the array is undefined

Comment: I clearly should have waited for more details before providing an answer...
State, mutations and actions look fine. Also, you provided an initial state...

If everything works properly inside your state, it might have something to do with the way you are dispatching the action. Couldn't you dispatch the 'dictionaries/getDictionaries'-action inside a created-hook of you top component?

Comment: Yeah but the thing is I don't have a top component. I have a bunch of components that don't share a common parent. Which is why I would like the call to be made from a single place instead of having it in every component :)

Comment: Dispatching the action inside the components that are holding the computed property 'cartDictionary' should be sufficient, imho. As long as you are using the right hook (something before "mounted"). This would be the right way in my opinion. But i get your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can watch cartDictionary and set another data variable.

like this

```
<h2 class="checkout-section__header" v-html="cartHeading"></h2>



data () {
    return {
      cartHeading: ''
    }
},
watch: {
  'cartDictionary': function (after, before) {
    if (after) {
      this.cartHeading = after
    }
  }
}
```

Because `this.$store.state.dictionaries.myDictionarie` is undefined at the the begining, vuejs can't map myDictionarie['core']. That's why your code is not working.

You can do this also

```
state: {
    dictionaries: {
        myDictionaries: {}
    }
}
```

and set the `dictionaries` key values during resolve.

Comment: Right, but I was hoping to avoid having to make "empty" props if possible. Is that even possible?

Comment: Can you try this                            
```cartDictionary() {
        const myDictionaries = this.$store.state.dictionaries.myDictionaries
        return myDictionaries && myDictionaries['cart'] || []
    }
```

Sorry for the formatting. :(

Comment: The good news is that it worked.. The bad news is that I don't understand what just happened lol. How does this even work?

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope that helps.